# Many-to-many connection for three models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have three models: School, Teacher and Pupil

```
public class Pupil
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FavouriteLesson { get; set; }

    public SchoolEntity School { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    public IList<DataLink> DataLink { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool DeepEnglishLearning { get; set; }
    public int? SchoolRating { get; set; }

    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }

    public IList<DataLink> DataLink { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public SchoolEntity School { get; set; }
    public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }

    public IList<DataLink> DataLink { get; set; }
}
```

And I have DataLinks class for making connections:

- a school can have many students and teachers
- pupils can have one school and many teachers
- teachers can have one school and many students

**DataLink.cs**

```
public class DataLink
{
   public int TeacherId { get; set; }
   public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

   public int PupilId { get; set; }
   public Pupil Pupil { get; set; }
}
```

How should I configure `OnModelCreating` method to make it work?

**DatabaseContext**

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<SchoolEntity> SchoolTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> TeacherTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pupil> PupilTable { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SchoolEntity>().ToTable("School");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().ToTable("Teacher");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pupil>().ToTable("Pupil");

        // Is it correct?
        modelBuilder.Entity<DataLink>()
            .HasOne(dl => dl.Teacher)
            .WithMany(dl => dl.DataLink)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DataLink>()
            .HasOne(dl => dl.Pupil)
            .WithMany(dl => dl.DataLink)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SirRufo Sorry, I updated the question. Pupil is a student

Comment: You only need the DataLink for the Many-To-Many relation between Pupil and Teacher. The One-To-Many relations between School-Teacher or School-Pupil do not need such a datalink table

Comment: @SirRufo I updated question - deleted School from `DataLink` and `DatabaseContext`. Is it how it should looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have extra properties for the link between students to teachers, you dont really need your DataLink class at all. EF can do a join table that is invisible to the code first model to handle this. As soon as you want an extra property this goes out the window though so choose wisely. You could use the following...

```
    public class Pupil
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FavouriteLesson { get; set; }

        public SchoolEntity School { get; set; }
        public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    }

    public class SchoolEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool DeepEnglishLearning { get; set; }
        public int? SchoolRating { get; set; }

        public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public SchoolEntity School { get; set; }
        public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
    }

    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {}

        public DbSet<SchoolEntity> SchoolTable { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teacher> TeacherTable { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pupil> PupilTable { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SchoolEntity>().ToTable("School");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().ToTable("Teacher");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Pupil>().ToTable("Pupil");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().HasRequired(r => r.School).WithMany(m => m.Teachers).HasForiegnKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Pupil>().HasRequired(r => r.School).WithMany(m => m.Pupils).HasForiegnKey(k => k.Id);
            //This will configure many-to-many with a join table. Use .Map to set the table name and key properties manually but EF will auto-name them if you dont
            modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().HasMany(x => x.Pupils).WithMany(x => x.Teachers); 
        }
    }
```